# AngularJS - Bootstrap popover with different tooltip on hover and click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Is there an easy way to have one tooltip for hovering and then another one for when you click it?

On hover:

```
<span data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Click to show details">{{ someData }}</span>
```

On click:

```
<span data-toggle="popover" title="More details" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-content="{{ someDetailedData }}">{{ someData }}</span>
```

Just using this directive to wrap the boostrap popover:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.utils")
        .directive("toggle", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    if (attrs.toggle == "tooltip") {
                        $(element).tooltip();
                    }
                    if (attrs.toggle == "popover") {
                        $(element).popover();
                    }
                }
            };
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use on `ng-mousedown="mouseov = false" and ng-mouseover="mouseov = true"` attribute
Than in title you can do something like

```
<span>< data-toggle="popover" title="{{mouseov 
   ? 'title on mouseover true' 
   : 'title on mousedown leave'}}"
   data-trigger="hover" data-content="Click to show details">{{ someData }}
</span>
```